# How would I go about solving this problem on freecodecamp.org? - css related

Tags: html, css, css-variables

The `.red-box` *rule* should include a *fallback* with the `background` set to `red` immediately before the existing `background` *declaration*.

Here is the pre-generated *code*:

```css
:root {
  --red-color: red;
}

.red-box {
  background: var(--red-color);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what they are looking for is for you to set `background: red;` immediately before `background: var(--red-color);` so that if the latter fails, `background: red;` will be used.

```css
:root {
  --red-color: red;
}

.red-box {
  background: red;
  background: var(--red-color);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-box"></div>
```

Comment: ^^ explanation : This way, if the css variable fails, it will just be outputted as an invalid syntax and use the one, that you put just before that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just put out the background.

```
root {
  --red-color: red;
}

.red-box {
  background: red;
  background: var(--red-color);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```